# How to clean HTML removing repeated paragraphs?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I´m trying to clean an html file that has repeated paragraphs within body. Below I show the input file and expected output.

**Input.html**
https://jsfiddle.net/97ptc0Lh/4/

**Output.html**
https://jsfiddle.net/97ptc0Lh/1/

I've been trying with the following code using BeautifulSoup but I don´t know why is not working, since the resultant list `CleanHtml` contains the repeated elements (paragraphs) that I´d like to remove.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = open("Input.html", "rb")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html5lib")

Uniques = set()
CleanHtml = []

for element in soup.html:
    if element not in Uniques:
        Uniques.add(element)
        CleanHtml.append(element)   

print (CleanHtml)
```

May someone help me to reach this goal please.

Comment: According to the output that you provided, the duplicates have been removed. What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: The output I show is the expected output. My current code is not doing that hehe.

Comment: My bad. Hint: `soup.html` has only two elements, the head and the body. An HTML document does not have a linear structure. It is a tree.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the hint. So, I need to do instead something like `soup.find_all('p')` to get I list with all paragraphs? If yes, how to  concatenate the rest of HTML elements that are not paragraphs without affecting the order in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
elms = []
for elem in soup.find_all('font'):
    if elem not in elms:
        elms.append(elem)
    else:
        target =elem.findParent().findParent()
        target.decompose()
print(soup.html)
```

This should get you your the desired output.

Edit:

To remove only for those paragraphs that have don't size 4 or 5, change the `else` block to

```
 else:
    if elem.attrs['size'] != "4" and elem.attrs['size'] !="5":
        target =elem.findParent().findParent()
        target.decompose()
```

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting for the help. I'm trying and with sample file it seems to work, the only issue I have found so far is that with input files having characters like `á, é, ñ, Á, É, Ó,Ñ etc`, when is sent `print(soup.html)` is showing those characters like `Â, Ã³, Ã�`. How to fix this?

Comment: @GerCas - It looks like an encoding problem; try changing `fp = open("Input.html", "rb")` to `fp = open("Input.html", "rb", encoding="utf-8")` or whatever the correct encoding is. Search around; that's a pretty common problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @GerCas - Not sure about your question without seeing the sample html. I would recommend you post it (as a new question; SO doesn't like extended discussions and more than one question) with nodes that both have and don't have grandparents; then I (and others) can take a look.

Comment: I get it. Thanks Jack one more time